# How to change floating action button in android?

Tags: android

I have a layout in which I added floating action button but it will stay in bottom I want to change position to above bottom bar which I implemented in layout .how can I do that

```
<include layout="@layout/controller_content"/>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/reload"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"/>
```

Comment: where you want it?? you have set properties inside it so its set at bottom remove it and set properties as u want

Comment: change its layout_gravity, to the position you want to set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your FloatingActionButton inside Relative layout and you can easily do that.